# "system resource exceeded" when running a function

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a field called "sku" which uniquely identifies products on the table, there are about 38k products. I have a "sku generator" which uses other fields in the table to create the SKU. It's worked perfectly without an issue until I started producing SKUs for a large amount of products. I would launch the generator and it would stop around 15,000 and say "System Resource exceeded" and highlight the following code in the function:

```
Found = IsNull(DLookup("sku", "Loadsheet", "[sku]='" & TempSKU & "'"))
```

I didn't have time to fully fix the issue, so a temporary fix for me was to split the database in two, and run the sku generator seperately on both files. Now that I have more time I want to investigate why exactly it gets stuck around this number, and if there's a possibility of fixing this issue (it would save some time with splitting files and then grouping them again). I also have an issue with it getting really slow at times, but I think it's because it's processing so much when it runs. Here is the function

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command2_Click() 'Generate SKU
Command2.Enabled = False: Command3.Enabled = False: Command2.Caption = "Generating ..."
Me.RecordSource = ""
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("ResetSKU").Execute
Me.RecordSource = "loadsheet_4"

Dim rs As Recordset, i As Long
Set rs = Me.Recordset
rs.MoveLast: rs.MoveFirst

For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
    rs.AbsolutePosition = i
    rs.Edit
    rs.Fields("sku") = SetSKU(rs)
    rs.Update
    DoEvents
Next
Command2.Enabled = True: Command3.Enabled = True: Command2.Caption = "Generate SKU"
End Sub


Public Function SetSKU(rs As Recordset) As String
Dim TempStr As String, TempSKU As String, id As Integer, Found As Boolean, ColorFound As Variant
id = 1: ColorFound = DLookup("Abbreviated", "ProductColors", "[Color]='" & rs.Fields("single_color_name") & "'")

TempStr = "ORL-" & UCase(Left(rs.Fields("make"), 2)) & "-"
TempStr = TempStr & Get1stLetters(rs.Fields("model"), True) & rs.Fields("year_dash") & "-L-"
TempStr = TempStr & "WR-"
TempStr = TempStr & IIf(IsNull(ColorFound), "?", ColorFound) & "-4215-2-"
TempStr = TempStr & rs.Fields("color_code")

TempSKU = Replace(TempStr, "-L-", "-" & ADDZeros(id, 2) & "-L-")
Found = IsNull(DLookup("sku", "Loadsheet", "[sku]='" & TempSKU & "'"))
While Found = False
    id = id + 1
    TempSKU = Replace(TempStr, "-L-", "-" & ADDZeros(id, 2) & "-L-")
    Found = IsNull(DLookup("sku", "Loadsheet", "[sku]='" & TempSKU & "'"))
Wend
If id > 1 Then
'    MsgBox TempSKU
End If

SetSKU = TempSKU
End Function


Public Function Get1stLetters(Mystr As String, Optional twoLetters As Boolean = False) As String
Dim i As Integer
Get1stLetters = ""

For i = 0 To UBound(Split(Mystr, " ")) 'ubound gets the number of the elements
    If i = 0 And twoLetters Then
        Get1stLetters = Get1stLetters & UCase(Left(Split(Mystr, " ")(i), 2))
        GoTo continueFor
    End If
    Get1stLetters = Get1stLetters & UCase(Left(Split(Mystr, " ")(i), 1))
continueFor:
Next
End Function



Public Function ADDZeros(N As Integer, MAX As Integer) As String
    Dim NL As Integer
    NL = Len(CStr(N))
    If NL < MAX Then
        ADDZeros = "0" & N 'StrDup(MAX - NL, "0") & N
    Else: ADDZeros = N
    End If
End Function
```

Notes: This function also calls other functions as well that adds a unique identifier to the SKU and also outputs the first letter of each word of the product

Also I'm running on 64 bit access.

If you require any other info let me know, I didn't post the other functions but if needed let me know.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure how you have split the Database into two files and that you are running the generator on both files. However I have a few suggestion to the function you are using.

I would not pass the recordset object to this function. I would rather pass the ID or unique identifier, and generate the recordset in the function. This could be a good start for efficiency.

Next, declare all objects explicitly, to avoid library ambiguity. rs As **DAO.Recordset**. Try to make use of inbuilt functions, like **Nz()**.

Could **Get1stLetters** method be replaced with a simple **Left()** function? How about **ADDZeros** method?

Using DLookup might be a bit messy, how about a DCount instead? Could the following be any use now?

```
Public Function SetSKU(unqID As Long) As String
    Dim TempStr As String, TempSKU As String
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim ColorFound As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    id = 1

    Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT single_color_name, make, model, year_dash, color_code " & _
                                     "FROM yourTableName WHERE uniqueColumn = " & unqID)

    ColorFound = Nz(DLookup("Abbreviated", "ProductColors", "[Color]='" & rs.Fields("single_color_name") & "'"), "?")

    TempStr = "ORL-" & UCase(Left(rs.Fields("make"), 2)) & "-"
    TempStr = TempStr & Get1stLetters(rs.Fields("model"), True) & rs.Fields("year_dash") & "-L-"
    TempStr = TempStr & "WR-"
    TempStr = TempStr & ColorFound & "-4215-2-"
    TempStr = TempStr & rs.Fields("color_code")

    TempSKU = Replace(TempStr, "-L-", "-" & ADDZeros(id, 2) & "-L-")

    While DCount("*", "Loadsheet", "[sku]='" & TempSKU & "'") <> 0 
        id = id + 1
        TempSKU = Replace(TempStr, "-L-", "-" & ADDZeros(id, 2) & "-L-")
    Wend

    If id > 1 Then
        'MsgBox TempSKU'
    End If

    Set rs = Nothing

    SetSKU = TempSKU
End Function
```

Comment: thank you for the response, As for Get1stletter it grabs the first two letters of the first word, then the first letter of every word after that. AddZeroes adds a number to the unique field of the sku, this is just in case there are two products with identical skus (sometimes we have cases like product 12 3 and product 12 30 that will produce the same sku). The addzeroes makes sure they're different. I changed the code but it gives me issues about the other functions, such as SetSku(rs) . I'll edit the entire code into my original post.

Comment: Since the SetSKU now takes in a Long, than a Recordset, you should change the calling function. Instead of having something like SetSKU(Me.Recordset) you would call something like SetSKU(Me.ID). Regarding all other functions. It was just an observation.